# Unclear how to use takewhile python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to get the divisor length of n (which is a list) if it divides the len(n) with no remainder.

```
i = takewhile(lambda d: len(n) % d == 0 for d in range(3, 6), n)
```

I have received following syntactical error

> Generator expression must be parenthesized if a not sole argument

So instead I modified my code to the following:

`i = takewhile((lambda d: len(n) % d == 0 for d in range(3, 6)), n)`

> itertools.takewhile at 0xa7075c8>

What am I going wrong?

Comment: Hold on, you define `d` double: in the generator and in the lambda. This does not make much sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it outputs `<itertools.takewhile at 0xa7075c8>` is because itertools produces generators, not lists. So the result is **not materialized** until you really need it (or wrap a `list(..)` around it).

Well as the compiler says, the **generator** should have parentesis, **not the entire lambda expression**. So:

```
i = takewhile(lambda d: (len(n) % d == 0 for d in range(3, 6)), n)
```

But we are not there yet: you define `d` both in the head of your lambda and in the generator, indeed:

```
i = takewhile(lambda d: (len(n) % d == 0 for d in range(3, 6)), n)
```

Finally you use `takewhile` the wrong way I think. As far as I know you want the first element that succeeds, you can simply call `.next()` on your constructed generator, so you probably want:

```
i = (d for d in range(3, 6) if len(n) % d == 0).next()
```

in Python-2, or:

```
i = next(d for d in range(3, 6) if len(n) % d == 0)
```

in Python-3.

Running this in an interpreter gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> i = next(d for d in range(3, 6) if len(n) % d == 0)
>>> i
3
>>> n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> i = next(d for d in range(3, 6) if len(n) % d == 0)
>>> i
5
```

Comment: I just started out with python, yeah I totally got it wrong -_-. Thank you for the brief explanation. :)